# I'm trying to open an app using Rosetta 2 and there isn't an option to

Tags: rosetta

When I inspect the app with Cmd + I all I see is the greyed-out locked button where I should also see the option to open with Rosetta. Other apps can be opened with Rosetta so I'm unsure if its application-specific or an issue I can fix.

Comment: What's the app [& version] ? Rosetta won't open 32-bit apps.

Comment: It might also be an Intel-only or Apple silicon only app.

Comment: What does it say under "Kind" in Get Info?

Comment: Application: Intel

Comment: Intel applications open with Rosetta by default, no option needed.